# Android studio - change color of NOT OF BOTTOM NAVIGATION VIEW

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change color of lower part in android studio
And I am not talking about bottom navigation view
I am talking about the three icons which are by default when open any app 
The icons are back button and home back and one square 
How can I change color of that

Image is highlighting of what I want to change color of

[image: Image is highlighting of what I want to change color of]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change those icons, they're device predefined icons for navigations.
You can how ever make it go away like below:

```
findViewById(R.id.your_layout).setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Note that this might not work on latest android devices as I have only done this on older version of android like >4.4
Also, it's really not a good idea removing as it's device specific...you don't want to break your device!

To change the color, you can try few methods below:

**1** From the class

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }
```

**2** as a style

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Update**
Due to the fact that you need to call `getWindow()` it will be impossible to run the code on Application class.

So, I will suggest a baseActivity instead...let it be known that, this suggestion is open for improvement.

There are multiple methods to get this done and they all have their down sides also.

**SUG ONE, create an open base class like below**

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.navigationBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.green)
        }
    }
}
```

**So in your activities, you will have:**

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

**instead of:**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

Note: I have a feeling this is costly.

**SUG TWO, since it's a single line of code, you can just run it across your activities, it basically have no optimizations effect or what so ever.**

Note: programmers call it redundancy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205797/discussion-on-answer-by-whales-corps-android-studio-change-color-of-not-of-bot).